# Sort index doesn't work for MySQL

Tags: mysql, index, order-by, mysql-8.0

I have a table with more than a million records. I get the data by using `LIMIT`, but also `ORDER BY`. The latter causes a huge performance problem.

My query ends with this:

```sql
... ORDER BY `record`.`timestamp` DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Executing this query takes more than 20s. If I'll remove `ORDER BY`, the execution time in `mysql` is `0.00` which is obviously a huge difference. I know why it happens - the DB needs to sort the data first, to apply `LIMIT` on it. I've noticed while profiling that the `Creating sort index` step takes a lot of time, so I've decided to create an index like that:

```sql
alter table record add index timestampidx (timestamp desc);
```

Unfortunately, it didn't change anything - the execution time is exactly the same as it was. The database I'm running is locally spawned by `docker-compose` with the following configuration:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: db-password
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to make my query faster?

### Edit:

The create statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `record` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `thread` int NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `pass` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `fail` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `cyc_lmt` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `diag_err` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `not_run` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass_cyc` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `eff` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpu_lmt` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`name`,`thread`),
  KEY `thread` (`thread`),
  KEY `timestampidx` (`timestamp` DESC),
  CONSTRAINT `record_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`thread`) REFERENCES `thread` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4006386 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The full query:

```sql
    SELECT  `record`.`id`, `record`.`name`, `record`.`thread`, `record`.`timestamp`,
            `record`.`pass`, `record`.`fail`, `record`.`cyc_lmt`,
            `record`.`diag_err`, `record`.`not_run`, `record`.`pass_cyc`,
            `record`.`eff`, `record`.`cpu_lmt`,
            `thread`.`id`, `thread`.`name`, `thread`.`config`,
            `config`.`id`, `config`.`name`, `config`.`regression`,
            `regression`.`id`, `regression`.`name`, `regression`.`instance`,
            `instance`.`id`, `instance`.`name`
        FROM  (`record`
        INNER JOIN  (`thread`
        INNER JOIN  (`config`
        INNER JOIN  (`regression`
        INNER JOIN  `instance`  ON `regression`.`instance` = `instance`.`id`
                    )  ON `config`.`regression` = `regression`.`id`
                    )  ON `thread`.`config` = `config`.`id`
                    )  ON `record`.`thread` = `thread`.`id`
              )
        ORDER BY  `record`.`timestamp` DESC
        LIMIT  5;
```

Execution plan with `ORDER BY`:

```sql
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys      | key        | key_len | ref                       | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | instance   | NULL       | index | PRIMARY            | name       | 258     | NULL                      |   14 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | regression | NULL       | ref   | PRIMARY,instance   | instance   | 4       | regressions.instance.id   |  125 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | config     | NULL       | ref   | PRIMARY,regression | regression | 4       | regressions.regression.id |    7 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | thread     | NULL       | ref   | PRIMARY,config     | config     | 4       | regressions.config.id     |   10 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | record     | NULL       | ref   | thread             | thread     | 4       | regressions.thread.id     |    8 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Execution plan without `ORDER BY`:

```sql
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys      | key        | key_len | ref                       | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | instance   | NULL       | index | PRIMARY            | name       | 258     | NULL                      |   14 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | regression | NULL       | ref   | PRIMARY,instance   | instance   | 4       | regressions.instance.id   |  125 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | config     | NULL       | ref   | PRIMARY,regression | regression | 4       | regressions.regression.id |    7 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | thread     | NULL       | ref   | PRIMARY,config     | config     | 4       | regressions.config.id     |   10 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | record     | NULL       | ref   | thread             | thread     | 4       | regressions.thread.id     |    8 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Are you sure that the index is created? Also, do you see it used if you try a simple `SELETC r.* FROM record AS r ORDER BY r.timestamp DESC LIMIT 5;`

Comment: Huh, it seems that it started working. I've tried to test a simple query and the result was instant. I've then used the original one, and again - instant result. The `Creating sort index` step is gone from profiling. Is it possible that the database needed some time to finish setting up the index? By that time I mean like a few hours.

Comment: Can you provide table structure for regression table ?

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the parenthesis in FROM clause the query is by fact

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM       `instance`
INNER JOIN `regression` ON `regression`.`instance` = `instance`.`id`
INNER JOIN `config`     ON `config`.`regression` = `regression`.`id`
INNER JOIN `thread`     ON `thread`.`config` = `config`.`id`
INNER JOIN `record`     ON `record`.`thread` = `thread`.`id`
ORDER BY `record`.`timestamp` DESC LIMIT 5;
```

The index by `record (timestamp ASC/DESC)` cannot be used for this query improvement.

Recommendation - use some `WHERE` clause by `record.timestamp` which selects a small part of rows but not less than 5 ones with guarantee. For example, `WHERE record.timestamp > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY`. And try to create an index `record (timestamp, thread)`.

Comment: I can't add `WHERE` clause, as I don't know how old is the oldest record I need. Isn't there another way to eliminate the `Creating sort index` step and use predefined index instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I have ever seen `JOINs` parenthesized like that.  Suggest you change to @Akina's way -- without parentheses.  That *may* even fix the performance problem.

If not, then turn the query inside-out:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT ... 
              FROM record
              ORDER BY timestamp DESC
              LIMIT 5
        ) AS r
    INNER JOIN ... ON ...
    INNER JOIN ... ON ...
    INNER JOIN ... ON ...
    INNER JOIN ... ON ...
    ORDER BY r.timestamp DESC   -- yes, again
```

However, this may fail to help.  It depends on whether the `JOINs` expand the number of rows, thereby invalidating the "5" that you started with.

And, yes, replace `INDEX(timestamp DESC)` with a 'covering' `INDEX(timestamp, thread)`.  (The `DESC` should not matter on any version of MySQL -- in *this* case.)